# Populating spinner dynamically using EditText and button

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
    myAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruits));        myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {edttxt.setText(fruits.get(position));}

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {}});
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            add();
        }});

}
private void add()  {
    String name=edttxt.getText().toString();
    if(!name.isEmpty() && name.length()>0)   {
        myAdapter.add(name);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        edttxt.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added" + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else   {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing to Add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to add items in spinner permanently but using this code it stores only temporarily i.e. Once I close the app and open again, all items in spinner are gone.

I want to add them permanently i.e once I add an item in spinner using button and EditText I should be stored in XML file.

Comment: @Virkrant Dharap  you have to use sharedprefrence to store data

Comment: you need to use one of the storage methods available in android API: SharedPrefrences, Files or Database (Sqlite)

Answer (score 1):

Hey Vikrant if you want to retain the values which you entered through edittext and button then you need to storage that data in some kind of storage. Then if you close the app and restart that app then app would  retrieve that data from that storage.

There are different type of data storage options available on Android:

1)Internal file storage: Store app-private files on the device file system.

2)External file storage: Store files on the shared external file system. This is usually for shared user files, such as photos.

3)Shared preferences: Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.

4)Databases: Store structured data in a private database.

Please go through this -
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html